# Target h1 on single post page

Tags: css

I have CSS in my theme making all H1 white. One post has a white background image so I want to target this post specifically and make the text grey.

h1.entry-title targets all pages correctly.

I have tried a few iterations of the below but can't get the one post to be targeted.

```
#postid-156.h1.entry-title {
    color: #666666 !important;
}
```

I'm new at CSS, so hopefully I'm close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
.post-156 h1{
     color: #666666 !important;
}
```

If one of your wrapper elements, like `<article>` is unsing `post_class()` the post ID becomes a class of this wrapper like `.post-156`. So you can say all h1 which are contained in a wrapper with the class `.post-156`

Another possibility, if your `<body>`-Tag is using `body_class()`:

```
.postid-156 h1{
    color: #666666 !important;
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Ref.:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Comment: Neither of these seem to work. Any further ideas?

Comment: Oops page was cached `.postid-156 h1{
    color: #666666 !important;
}` worked:)